# How do I select a "random" (hashed) MUI palette color?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

Say I have a [chart series](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/styling/#series-color), or some other component that can take on a wide range of values that I'd like to colorize by value, but for which the color doesn't have any semantic information (i.e. it's not "success", "error", "warning", etc.) What's the best way to select a "random" color that looks good with my MUI palette?

Ideally, the solution should be deterministic bashed on the value; i.e. the same value should return the same color every time. (I.e., the color is a form of hashing.)

Comment: [color-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-hash) just hash the value as a string

Comment: @mocha This is what I'm doing now. The crux of the question is: how do I get a color *from my MUI palette*?

Comment: Why don't you just `arrayOfColors[value % numberOfColors]`